# React JS - avoid multiple imports in react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Currently the examples I read are kind of:

```
import Home from './components/Home';
import About from './components/About ';
import Login from './components/Login ';
//...
import 404 from './components/404';

<Router history={browserHistory}>
  <Route path='/' component={Home}>
    <Route path='login' component={login} />
    <Route path='about' component={about} />
    ...
    <Route path='404' component={404} />
    <AssembliesRoutes />
  </Route>
</Router>
```

I want to know how to avoid the multiple imports, I mean, how to scale with `react-router`?

Answer (score 3):

One way could be to optimize your component exports:

**index.js**

```
export { default as Home } from './Home'
export { default as About } from './About '
export { default as Login } from './Login '
export { default as 404 } from './404'
```

That way, you're able to just reference the named export:

**Route.js**

```
import { Home, About, Login, 404 } from './components'

<Router history={browserHistory}>
   ...
</Router>
```

Comment: But when you have a more complicated structure? I mean something like: `dashboard/home`, `dashboard/profile`, `dashboard/settings`? Can I create a component inside the dashboard home containing all the routes? In Angular2 I used to separate routes for each high order components and its children

Comment: Oh, as in exporting a fully qualified `Route` component, like (`<Route path='login' component={login} />`), and then importing that? That's an interesting approach, I don't see why it couldn't work. I guess the nice part about having "hefty" routes file is you _can_ see all the individual routes, as oppose to maybe having to navigate to the different imports to see what `Route`s you're getting. But it's worth a shot!

Answer (score 3):

**Note:** I am writing this answer based on the comments in @lux's answer

One important thing to understand about React Router (v2/3) `<Route>` components is that they do not render anything. They are just used to build a configuration object.

```
<Route path="login" component={Login} />
```

Will be converted into the object:

```
{
  path: "login",
  component: Login
}
```

You can also create your own `routes` object and pass it to your `<Router>` using the `routes`prop.

```
<Router routes={routes} history={browserHistory} />
```

Knowing this, you could export a route object from each of your components and use them to compose a route object.

```
// dashboard/profile.js
class Profile extends React.Component {...}
export default {
  path: 'profile',
  component: Profile
}
```

Do something like that for each of your routes, and then in the `dashboard/index.js` file:

```
// dashboard/index.js
import ProfileRoute from './profile'
// etc.

export default {
  path: 'dashboard',
  component: Dashboard,
  childRoutes: [
    ProfileRoute
    ...
  ]
}
```

You could them compose that exported object as well as other route objects together to create the primary `route` object which you will pass to your `<Router>`.